# Laravel 4 : How are Facades resolved?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've kind of looking at what's going on Laravel 4 **facades** under the hood.

Let's take this Facade as an example:

```
File::get(someArgs);
```

If i'm not mistaken, the step by step (oversimplified) invocation would be:

```
//static method invocation which are all extended from Facade class
File::__callStatic(get, someArgs)
//returns an instance of FileSystem
File::resolveFacedeInstance('files') 
FileSystem->get(someArgs)
```

What I'am confused about is in the commented line below of the method **File::resolveFacadeInstance()** below:

```
protected static function resolveFacadeInstance($name)
{
    if (is_object($name)) return $name;

    if (isset(static::$resolvedInstance[$name]))
    {
        return static::$resolvedInstance[$name];
    }



    /**
    * The line that i'm confused about
    */

    return static::$resolvedInstance[$name] = static::$app[$name];
}
```

My questions are:

- How is **File::$app** even initialized or assigned a value inside the Facade class
- If **File::get()** is the invoked Facade

  **static::$app[$name]** would resolve to i think Application['files']
  or Application->files which in turn calls Application->__get('files') since there's no   **files** property inside **Application** class.

  How would FileSystem Class be return if this is only the content of this method?

  ```
  public function __get($key)
  {
      return $this[$key];
  }
  ```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'll try to describe in short :

So, you already know that `resolveFacadeInstance` method is called via `__callStatic` method of `Facade` class and component's Facade `(i.e. File extends Facade)` extends this `Facade` class.

During the boot-up process of the framework, from `public/index.php` following line starts the execution of `bootstrap/start.php` file

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
```

So, in this (`bootstrap/start.php`) file you can see some code like

```
// the first line, initiate the application
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
// ...
// ...
// notice this line
require $framework.'/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php';
// ...
// last line
return $app;
```

In this code snippet, `require $framework.'/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php';` line starts the execution of `Foundation/start.php` file and in this file you may see something like this

```
// ...

Facade::clearResolvedInstances();
// Notice this line
Facade::setFacadeApplication($app);
```

This (given above) line sets `application` instanse to `$app` property in the `Facade` class

```
// support/Facades/Facade.php
public static function setFacadeApplication($app)
{
    static::$app = $app;
}
```

Then in the `Foundation/start.php` file at the bottom, you can see something like this

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Core Service Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The Illuminate core service providers register all of the core pieces
| of the Illuminate framework including session, caching, encryption
| and more. It's simply a convenient wrapper for the registration.
|
*/

$providers = $config['providers'];

$app->getProviderRepository()->load($app, $providers);

$app->boot();
```

In this code snippet given above, all the core components registered by the framework and as you know that, every component has a service provider class (i.e. `FilesystemServiceProvider`) and in every service provider class there is a method `register` which is (for `FilesystemServiceProvider`)

```
/**
 * Register the service provider.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->app['files'] = $this->app->share(function() { return new Filesystem; });
}
```

Well, in this case `$this->app['files']` setting (`return new Filesystem`) an anonymous function, which returns the `filesystem` when gets executed

```
$this->app['files'] = $this->app->share(function() { return new Filesystem; });
```

to `$app['files']` so, when you call the `File::get()`, it finally calls the anonymous function and in this case, the following line

```
return static::$resolvedInstance[$name] = static::$app[$name];
```

Calls the function for `static::$app['file'];` and this function returns the instance but before returning, it stores the instance in the `$resolvedInstance` variable, so, next time it can return the instance from the variable without calling the anonymous function again. 
So, it looks like that, `static::$resolvedInstance[$name] = static::$app[$name];` calls the anonymous function which returns the instance and this function was registered earlier, when the `app` was started through boot up process.

**Important :**

`Application` extends `Container` and `Container` extends [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) class and that's why, a property of the `$app` object could be (accessed) set/get using array notation.

I've tried to give you an idea but you have to look in to the code, step by step, you won't get it only reading/tracking the code once.

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna look it up. Really appreciate your effort.
I didn't even know where to start in reading the source. You're really of big help.