# What does the Laravel serviceprovider do?

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel project (listing cms), which has the ability to run a query automatically. When I create a new record, it checks the date of that record and runs some queries to the database. Does this mean the `serviceprovider` is running all the time?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Laravel generates PHP and PHP doesn't work all the time but is called by HTTP requests..

Comment: [Check this, may help you.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20440143/741747)